# Validating custom slot types on Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have a simple utterance with a slot, e.g.

`Start {function}`

This function is defined as a custom slot type which can take two values, `a` and `b`.  So if the user types in `c` for example, I simply want to keep asking them to reenter the data.  I have made the slot type as **required** in the console and I can successfully tell if the value is not one from the list.  What I am having trouble with is, what do I show next...I have tried this:

`return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
          .getResponse();`

And

`return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .prompt('Wrong input')
            .addElicitSlotDirective(SLOT_NAME)
            .getResponse();`

But both of the above keep hitting my error handler.  Is there an example online for this? Or can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here, [ask-core-docs](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/wiki/Response-Building) it seems that the appropriate syntax for what you are trying to do is `addElicitSlotDirective(slotToElicit: string, updatedIntent?: Intent)`, which might explain why your code execution keeps hitting the error handler, please try changing it and let me know if that fixes your problem